# To which symmetry group is the original symmetry group of a theory broken when we add to the theory a scalar field with a VEV?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, gauge-theory, group-theory, higgs, symmetry-breaking

If one has a gauge theory with a specific symmetry group and we add to it a scalar field with a non-zero VEV, how do we know in general to which symmetry group will the original symmetry be spontaneously broken?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is broken to whichever  subgroup of the original group that leaves the VEV unchanged.

Answer (score 0):

@mike stone 's answer is impeccable, but requires emphasizing that the answer therefore depends on the *representation of the Higgs multiplet* under that group.

For most of the groups used in physics, this was done in a legendary paper [*Group theory of the spontaneously broken gauge symmetries*, Ling-Fong Li (1974), *Phys Rev*  **D9**  1723](https://journals.aps.org/prd/abstract/10.1103/PhysRevD.9.1723), routinely used as a "phonebook" if you don't recall the standard answers.